# Document Set Name field is empty on View all properties page

Tags: 2013, form, document-set

Sharepoint 2013 EE (installed not by me).
What do I do:

1. Create new **Web application**
2. Create **Site collection** in it
3. Add **Document Set** Content type to default ***Documents*** library
4. Create new document set instance, set ***Name*** and ***Description*** fields
5. Open this document set properties (**View all properties** button)

Problem: ***Name*** field is empty. There's a column named "***Name***" in a left part of the window, but no column's value in a right part.
On a **Document Set** *Welcome page* ***Name*** column's value is present.

Any ideas?

Comment: Good day. Have you ever found a solution for this? I am noticing the same thing.

Comment: which version of SharePoint cumulative update installed in your machine.? @Fox --> where you able to find a solution for it.?

Comment: Actually I did find a solution for the problem. I edited the document set welcome page but didn't make any changes to it. After saving, the issue was fixed